# how to send the emailable-report to specific recipient in TestNg framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

After executing the test suit through Testng framework, I don't have any idea on how to send the report through email. How to use emailable-report.html to be send a specific recipient?

Comment: Are you using Jenkins or some CI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use testngxslt plugin and integrate ANT when generated a build.xml file BY using

javax mailjar and javax activation jar trying to send report as zip file.

Comment: can pls explain  the details way of doing ?

Comment: [link]http://www.abodeqa.com/2014/02/13/emailing-xslt-report-in-webdriverjava-using-ant-build-xml-automatically/ Follow this for emaiing the reports

Comment: Refer this [Link]http://selenium-suresh.blogspot.in/2013/02/ant-generating-selenium-reports-using.html for generating testng xslt reports through ant build.xml file

Comment: Thanks raghuveer for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a java class to send email using javax and then set it as a final task in your build.xml.( if you are using ant to build and run you can use this, it works fine for us)